# Greedy algorithm to find potential weighted activities in order?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

For example, let's say there's a list of activities {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}

```
a & b are worth 9 points each. 
c is worth 8 points. 
d & e are worth 6 points each. 
f is worth 5 points.
g is worth 4 points.
```

The list of activities is already sorted by points descending.

I want to find the highest points combination of three activities (let's call this combination X) that fulfills certain requirements (such that F(X) = true).

F(X) accepts only a combination of three activities, and cannot be modified.

<s>How can I generate X without first having to calculate all possible combinations?</s>
How can I iterate through all the possible combinations in decreasing total points?

I want to be able to find the highest point combination, test it. If it fails, generate second-highest point combination, etc.

The example list is only a few items. However, the actual list can get extremely large that and it would be impractical to generate all combinations.

How should I do this?

Comment: what is F(X) ? Without it i am afraid you cannot make non-brute force solution in any way

Comment: I'm not saying find non-brute solution, but I want to input combinations in order of points. So first test {a, b, c} then try {a, b, d}, etc.

Comment: You're trying to **iterate** through all possible combinations in decreasing total points. I edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's partially my fault that the two that answered didn't understand me :(

Comment: F(X) does NOT determine the value of each combination. It only returns true or false, however, the important property of F(X) is that it accepts only a set of three activities. Each activity already has a weight, is there no way to output combinations in descending order without first computing every combination? Getting the MAX is easy. We just select the first three items in the list.

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri I didn't read your question carefully, my bad. I deleted my previous comment

Comment: It's going to be interesting to get the proper order of combinations. The first two are obvious, `a,b,c` and `a,b,d`. But what should come next, `a,b,e` or `a,c,d`? Consider the sequences `9,8,7,6,4` and `9,8,6,5,4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following idea only solves an easier version of the problem, but maybe it can be extended to a more powerful solution.

Let [a(1)..a(N)] be the input array. 
What I suggest here is a way to enumerate the top N^(1/3) triplets, out of the C(N,3)~N^3 ones in the complete enumeration. I know this is modest, but it guarantees **O(N) time and space**.

1. s = a(1) + a(2) + a(N^(1/3))
2. T = All triplets in [a(1),a(2), .. ,a(N^(1/3))] (takes O(N) time and space)
3. Sort T in descending triplet sum order (Time complexity: O(N^(1/3) * log N) = O(N) )
4. Iterate over T and return every triplet r while sum(r) >= s

**Explanation:**

In (1) we compute the highest score possible for a triplet that doesn't involve only items from T = [a(1)..a(N^(1/3))]. In other words, T already contains all triplets of score > s. Therefore we generate all triplets in T, sort them, and return only the ones we are sure about (i.e. the ones with score>=s). How many such triplets will be returned? well, this depends on the array values, but we can guarantee at least N^(1/3) - 2 triplets, since all triplets [a(1)+a(2)+a(i)] for `2<i<=N^(1/3)` have a sum >=s. In practice the number of "good" triplets may be much higher, but again, this depends on the array numbers distribution.

Comment: Is this simply creating and sorting triplets made of the first third of the list of activities? Sorry I think I'm confused. Thanks for your time and for clearing misunderstandings in other answers.

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri: Not third - but a much smaller part of the list - N^(1/3) items from it (i.e. the cube root of the length). Sorting only the triplets produced by this small portion allows returning at least the top N^(1/3) triplets, and it only uses O(N) space, compared with the full sorting that needs O(N^3) space.

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri: For example, if the input list has length 10^9, you take the first 1000 items, produce the 166,167,000 triplets, sort them in descending order, and then start returning triplets until you encounter a sum lower than a(1)+a(2)+a(1000).

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Yeah I see how that would work. Is there a way I can go about this without first having to store 166m triplets? That could be a little too much.

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri: It depends how many results you need. If top 100 results are enough, use the first 100 items, which produce only 161,700 triplets. An additional optimization would be to create a triplet only if it has a sum greater than the bound s (a(1)+a(2)+a(100) in this case). This way the triplet array is even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a great solution for your requirement. Here is the best (and worst) solution I can think of: Generate all combinations put them in a vector then sort! Complexity is `O(n^3 log(n^3))`. Only little improvement I think can be achieve by assuming that there is no point of having same value in the same position multiple times as it will generate a combination already got generated.

Implementation in c++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Combin {
    int a, b, c, sum;
};

bool comp(Combin a, Combin b) {
    return a.sum>b.sum;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> act;
    int n;
    while(scanf("%d", &n)==1 && n) {
        act.push_back(n);
    }

    vector<Combin>combs;

    for (int i=0; i<act.size(); i++) {
        if (i>0 && act[i-1]==act[i]) continue;
        for (int j=i+1; j<act.size(); j++) {
            if (j>i+1 && act[j-1]==act[j]) continue;
            for (int k=j+1; k<act.size(); k++) {
                if (k>j+1 && act[k-1]==act[k]) continue;
                    Combin comb;
                    comb.a=i; comb.b=j; comb.c=k;
                    comb.sum = act[i]+act[j]+act[k];
                    combs.push_back(comb);
            }
        }
    }

    sort(combs.begin(), combs.end(), comp);

    for (int i=0; i<combs.size(); i++) {
        printf("(%d,%d,%d)=%d\n", act[combs[i].a], act[combs[i].b], act[combs[i].c], combs[i].sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: all possible three-activity combination is only (n choose 3) not n!. I understand what you're trying to do with the nested loops but it's too slow. That was the first thing I tried, except the initial value of j is j = i + 1, and k is j + 1. However, with only 1000 activities, n^3 is a 1 billion, and n choose 3 is still 166 million, which although is much better, is still not quick enough.

Comment: Actually I answer this because it was not clear to me what you mean by all combination, anyways it seem you need a better solution than O(n^3) but how much improvement can be done will highly depend on your function F(X), so describing how that function verify a combination will help you get better answer.

Comment: For the sake of not being too specific that this question doesn't help anyone else, you can safely assume F(X) is basically user input. The user has to decide if this is the right combination for them or not.

Comment: If the user function is too wild than there is no room for being greedy, user rule set can be something like "'a' can not be in the same set with 'b'", "'c' and 'd' should be always togather" or "summation of two number must be bigger than the third" etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'll try explaining with hypothetical situation. Let's say there's 10,000 different activities. The activities are not all equal, some are worth a lot, some are worth very little. The user does not see what the activities are worth, he can only say if he likes it or not. We are looking for the combination that is worth the most points and liked by the user (i.e F(X) is true). Also, can you explain what you mean by "too wild"?

Comment: If a combination is liked by user then there can be two ways to get the input, 1. User give all the liked combination and all your program will do is iterate through that list and find the highest valued combination. 2. Your program will show each combination one by one, user like some of those combination and the program save the highest valued comb upon each like.

Comment: ignore what F(X) does, it's irrelevant. Ignore user input for now. I want to iterate through all the possible combinations in decreasing total points.

Comment: that would not generate possible answers in decreasing total points. It would generate {a,b,c}{a,b,d}{a,b,e}{a,b,f}{a,b,g} in that order, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: {a,b,d} and {a,b,e} will have same value {9,9,6} and {9,9,6}, you do not want that? And yes, the above code will generate comb from bigger to smaller or equal order but never bigger.

Comment: {b,c,d} is worth 23 points. {a,b,g} is worth 22. However, your code will generate {a,b,g} before {b,c,d}. So, yes, it will generate bigger value and not in descending order.

Comment: Your latest change suggests creating all combinations then sorting them. This is literally the exact (and only?) thing I'm asking to avoid.

Comment: Generate all triples then sort them is the only way to do what you ask to the precision you suggest so far. If you have no room for compromise then I guess we are done.

Comment: @Paddy3118: Assuming that generating all triplets is the only possible way to meet all requirements is incorrect. Actually there's a solution that requires O(N^2) space, and returns the next item in O(log N) time. Your solution is O(N^3) space, it requires a O(N^3*log N) pre-process time, and then it returns next items in O(1). The reason I don't submit my solution is because it's still not good enough in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: @EyalSchneider: There are O(N^3) triplets to generate, and you are generating each of them in O(log N), that means your solution required `O(N^3 log N)` times, still it is better than my solution `O(N^3 log(N^3))` and also yours one take only O(N^2). Basically your not yet submitted solution is better than all the solution presented here. so please do submit.

Comment: @sowrov: Note that O(N^3*log N) = O(N^3*Log (N^3)). The constant exponent in the log can be moved outside as a multiplier. Anyway, I'm less interested in total running time (which I agree - it must be at least O(N^3)). The question is how to improve the memory usage, and maintain a reasonable iteration time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to generate ordered combinations of three:-

```
    for(int i=0;i<Set.size();i++) {

       for(int j=i+1;j<Set.size();j++) {

           for(int k=j+1;k<Set.size();k++) {

                   if(F(Set[i],Set[j],Set[k])) {
                       // your code to find max
                   }  
           }
       }

}
```

Comment: this will still generate all possible combinations of three. I need to generate them in a certain order. Most points to least.

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri What will be it for {a,b,c,d}?

Comment: {a, b, c, d} shouldn't even be combined in the first place. That's 4 activities. I'm looking for three item combinations. How can I iterate through all the possible three-item combinations in decreasing total points?

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri As all combinations of three are unique hence all possible combinations of three will satisfy that constraints

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri I was asking  if your ordered list is {a,b,c,d} then what are the combinations u need?

Comment: F(X) returns true or false. We don't know what it will return. F({a,b,c}) can be false, or it can be true. I need a way to test combinations in decreasing total points.

Comment: @EyalSchneider And how exactly will they have illegal array indices?

Comment: @EyalSchneider Actually i think he doesnt need my solution because unfortunately he also has values where multiple elements have same value in that case this solution doesnt work as expected. Dont have time for writing exact solution but will do it later :(

Comment: @VikramBhat: I don't think the solution fails because of duplicate values. Consider the following example: {10,9,6,2,1,0}. The triplet {10,1,0} comes earlier than {9,6,2} in your iteration order, but has lower sum.

Comment: @EyalSchneider Good point there. Didn't get his actual question while posting the solution

Answer (score 0):

I remembered that Pythons combinations generator tends to keep the LHS-to-RHS of its input varying from the least-to-most, and outputs the LHS terms first.

If you use Pythons method of generating combinations, which its [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) states is the following:

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Then you can just give the function your items in decreasing weight order to generate items in decreasing weight order:

```
for x in combinations('abcdef', 3): 
    print(x)

('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'f')
('a', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'c', 'e')
('a', 'c', 'f')
('a', 'd', 'e')
('a', 'd', 'f')
('a', 'e', 'f')
('b', 'c', 'd')
('b', 'c', 'e')
('b', 'c', 'f')
('b', 'd', 'e')
('b', 'd', 'f')
('b', 'e', 'f')
('c', 'd', 'e')
('c', 'd', 'f')
('c', 'e', 'f')
('d', 'e', 'f')
```

Note: As Essam points out in the comments, combinations(data, 3) is equivalent to comb3(data) where:

```
def comb3(data):
    lendata = len(data)
    for i in range(lendata):
        for j in range(i+1, lendata):
            for k in range(j+1, lendata):
                yield (data[i], data[j], data[k])
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be the equivalent of 
`for (i = 0, i < list.size; i++){
    for (j = i+1; j < list.size; j++){
        for (k = j+1; k < list.size; k++){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri: Yep - prepended a note to answer.

Comment: that doesn't let me iterate over three-item combinations in order of total points :(

Comment: Howso? It does for me. Can you give a concrete example of what is failing for you - maybe there is a miscommunication? If 'abcdef' is the items in decreasing order of weight then the triples returned will be in decreasing total weight order.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean now. You could either 1: Accept the partial ordering. 2: Use the series but discard triples that are greater than the one before. 3: Use my next recipe that I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer of just using generated combinations in a certain order doesn't give the fully sorted answer. In fact their will be 6 out of 35 occasions where the total for the next triple goes up rather than down.

If we use the combinations but put them in a heap of fixed maximum size then we can trade the maximum heap size for accuracy of sort like so:

```
from itertools import combinations
from heapq import heappush, heappop, heappushpop

BESTOFLAST = 10     # max heap size

item2points = dict(a=9, b=9, c=8, d=6, e=6, f=5, g=4)

def partially_ordered_triples(item2points, BESTOFLAST=BESTOFLAST):
    ordereditems = sorted(item2points.keys(), 
                        key=lambda item: item2points[item],
                        reverse=True)
    #print(ordereditems)    # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'g']

    triples = combinations(ordereditems, 3)

    heap = []   # Empty heap

    # Preload heap
    for i in range(BESTOFLAST):
        triple = triples.next()
        total = sum(item2points[item] for item in triple)
        heappush(heap, (-total, triple))    # minheap so -total

    # load/remove from heap in partially sorted order    
    for triple in triples:
        total = sum(item2points[item] for item in triple)
        thistotal, thistriple = heappushpop(heap, (-total, triple))
        yield thistriple, -thistotal

    # drain rest of heap
    while heap:
        thistotal, thistriple = heappop(heap)
        yield thistriple, -thistotal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for heapsize in range(BESTOFLAST + 1):
        print('Using a heap of size: %i and skipping:' % heapsize)
        length = skipped = 0
        previoustotal = sum(item2points.values())   # Starting high value
        for triple, newtotal in partially_ordered_triples(item2points, heapsize):
            if newtotal > previoustotal: skipped += 1
            length += 1
            previoustotal = newtotal

        print(" of %i triples, %i were skipped to keep the total count decreasing" % (length, skipped))
```

If the size of the heap is large enough then there will be no deviations from the required order. If too small then the number of deviations increases:

The output:

```
Using a heap of size: 0 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 6 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 1 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 4 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 2 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 4 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 3 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 3 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 4 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 2 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 5 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 2 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 6 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 1 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 7 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 1 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 8 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 1 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 9 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 0 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
Using a heap of size: 10 and skipping:
 of 35 triples, 0 were skipped to keep the total count decreasing
```

Comment: @EssamAl-Mansouri: Feedback? P.s. could you also remember to accept one of the answers to your questions. Thanks.

Comment: The accuracy increases as you increase the "look-ahead" size in your heap - This is obvious. However, what is missing is a way to set the suitable heap size (as a function of the input array length N), so that no iteration errors occur. If you can prove that the heap size is O(N), then this option is interesting. The required heap size also depends on the insertion logic. How do you scan items to create the triplets?

Comment: Set heapsize to N-1 for guaranteed decreasing order of total points count. You would have to experiment with samle data to see what trade-off you could live with. If none then it equates to generatingand sorting all triplets whereupon a different sort routine may prove better.

Comment: "Set heapsize to N-1 for guaranteed decreasing order of total points count" - what makes you think so? If N is the number of items, the number of triplets is proportional to N^3. If what you say is true (and it depends on the order you insert stuff into the heap), then it requires a proof.

Comment: @Paddy3118: I'm sorry friend, I only just saw this answer. The problem with your suggestion is that "combinations(ordereditems, 3)" alone would be too costly. With an example list such as abcdefg, it's okay. But when you make that list 150 elements, for example, that's already calculating over 500,000 possible combinations. As the main post said, it's impractical to calculate all possible combinations first in these scenarios.